# Only one call function is working at a time

Tags: python

I'm a bit lost, I modified a program to read from a text file but when I try to run the program it only runs one of the call functions and errors out on the third call function. When I run them one at at time they work find, can you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
import sys
def spacejam(diff3):
        '''Used to create spaces between the end of the max length and the students'''
    if len(diff3) == 23:
        space = (" " * 2)
    else:
        space = (" " * (25 - len(diff3)))
return space

def part1(courses):
'''Used to create table 1 of the assignment (printing Department Code,
   Course Number, and Students and finding the total number of students)'''
    total = 0
    for aline in courses: #for loop to check each line of the text file
        values = aline.split() #splits each line into elements
        diff = values[:2] #Sets diff to elements 0-1
        diff = ''.join(diff) #joins elements 0 and 1
        temp = values[-1] #sets temp to the last element
        temp = int(temp)   #makes the last elemet a interger
        total = total + temp #Adds the total of the intergers
        print(diff, values[-1].rjust(4)) #prints the needed values

     print("Total number of students: ", total)  # prints total

def part2(courses):
    '''Used to create table 2 of the assignment (printing Department Code,
    Course Number, Title, and Students)
    limiting the length of the Title to 23 characters'''
    for items in courses:  # For loop for every element in courses
        diff = items.split()  # Splits the elements in courses
        diff2 = diff[2:-1]  # combines elements 2 through -1(not including the last item)
        sep = ' '  # Sets the seperator to space
        diff3 = sep.join(diff2)  # Joins elements 2 through -1 as a string
        diff3 = ('%.23s' % diff3)  # Sets the character limit to 23 and shortens strings over 23 
         #characters
    print(diff[0], diff[1], diff3, spacejam(diff3), diff[-1].rjust(4))  # Prints the results

def part3(courses):
    '''Used to create table 2 of the assignment (printing Department Code,
    Course Number, Title, and Students) sorting the elements in a list and
    lining up the number of students'''
    lines = courses.readlines()
    maxlength = len(max(lines, key=len))

    for items in lines:  # For loop for every element in courses
        diff = items.split()  # Splits the each element in course
        diff2 = diff[:-1]  # Combines elements back together except the last element (-1)
        sep = ' '  # Sets the seperator to space
        diff3 = sep.join(diff2)  # Joins elements except the last element(-1) to a string
        space = (" " * (maxlength - len(diff3)))  # Add spaces between the elements based on the 
       #maxlength
    print(diff3, space, diff[-1].rjust(4))  # Prints results



def main():
    sys.setrecursionlimit(3500000)
    opencourse = open('courses.txt', 'r') #opens and reads a text file

    part1(opencourse)   #calls function part 1
    print('')

    part2(opencourse)  #calls function part 2
    print('')

    part3(opencourse)
    opencourse.close()  #closes opened text file
    main()
```

Here is what happens when I run this:

```
CS152   21 
CS369    8
CS365  119
CS208   24
CS319   14
MA221   12
MA311    7
MA150   27
CS335   20
IS361   22
MG315    6
Total number of students:  280
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\lord_\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Week 6 assignment 1.py",
> line 76, in 
> main()   File "C:\Users\lord_\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Week 6 assignment 1.py", line 74, in main
> part3(opencourse)   File "C:\Users\lord_\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Week 6 assignment 1.py",
> line 52, in part3
> maxlength = len(max(lines, key=len)) ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: please reformat your code to be valid (not starting with `'''`)

Answer (score 2):

The `opencourse` object is an iterator; each time you read from it, it internally keeps track of what you've read, and once you've read everything, you can't read any more.  When you do `for aline in courses` in your first function you're reading through the entire iterator, after which point it's basically "empty".  You then pass that same iterator to your other functions, and they have nothing to do because there's nothing left to read.

Rather than passing the file object to each function, I'd suggest using `readlines()` up front to turn it into a list of strings, and then pass that list around to each function; unlike an iterator, iterating through a list doesn't change the list.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: @Zelow It is not a dumb question. I'd argue that it's a pretty good question overall: it included a reproducible example, expected vs actual behavior, and was answerable in a concise but non-trivial answer.